# Is filtered selection faster than fetching all the rows and then filtering

Tags: mysql, sql

So I want to create a table in the frontend where I will list every single user. The thing is that the tables are relational and I have to get data from multiple tables in order to fulfill my goal.

Now here comes my question (keep in mind I have a MySQL database) :

Which method is better on the long run :

1. Generate joined queries that fetch all the data from each table where a user has any information (it outputs ~80 column per row and only 15 of them are needed)
2. Fetch the data that I need with multiple queries and then just "stick" the values together and output them (15 columns and all of them are needed, but I have to do extra work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to go for third option.

**Generate joined queries that fetch only necessary 15 columns for your front end. It would be the most efficient way.**

If you are facing challenges with joining the tables then you can share table structures with sample data and desired output here with your query. We can try to help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Can I select specific rows from a table and specific rows from another table in a single query ? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: @cristi_nmr it seems you need to use a join - there are tons of tutorials out there and tons of questions here on SO about it. However, we cannot be sure as your question is very vague!

Comment: I didn't know I can JOIN the tables, I looked it up and it looks like it can do what I want to do, thank you

Comment: @cristi_nmr you are most welcome. If you face any difficulties with join please let me know. I will try to help you. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

I don't understand your first option.  Why would you be selecting columns that you don't need?  If there are 15 columns that you specifically want, then select those columns and nothing else.

In general, it is faster to have the database do most of the work.  It can take advantage of its optimizer to produce the best execution plan that it can.

Comment: Well my query started like this "SELECT * FROM table1, table2 ...", I tried to write it like this "SELECT first_name, last_name FROM table1, height, weight FROM table2" but it didn't really work (just looking at the query I knew it wasn't going to work, but I tried it anyways ...)

Comment: @cristi_nmr - Use `JOIN .. ON`, where you specify how the tables are related in the `ON` clause.  There are over 8K examples on stackoverflow.

Comment: I did it already after someone told me about JOIN on tables, thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

From Experience with embedded hardware mysql server.

If the hardware can do it and has enough resources you let the databse server run it course, as it can run its optimizer.

But if the server hardware lags on some fronts, you transpport all data to the client and let it run Javascript on all returned data.

The same goes for bandwith of the internet connection, it is slow, you want lesser number of rows, to transport because that the user will notice it, even old smartphones have to much power in cpu, amd can so handle everything with easy what you through at them.

In Basic there is no sime answer, you have to check server hardware and the usual bandwith offered and then program a solution that works best

Comment: Well the performance is not an issue on the server side, but I definitely think there is a better way to fetch those rows

Comment: if the server has enough power, filterit in the server as it sends less data, that is always faster

Answer (score 0):

A simple Rule of Thumb:

Fewer round-trips to the database server is usually the faster alternative.